# JPA Conflict with Hibernate and Weblogic

Tags: hibernate, weblogic, jpa-2.0, fortify

I am trying to deploy my application and web service to weblogic using the following versions:

- Weblogic 10.3.5
- Hibernate 4.1.1
- Hibernate JPA API 2.0
- EJB 2.0
- Java 6

When I call my web service I get the error

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:Fault xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>ns2:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>javax/persistence/OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z</faultstring>
        <detail>
           <ns2:exception class="java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" note="To disable this feature, set com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace system property to false" xmlns:ns2="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/">
               <message>javax/persistence/OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z</message>
               <ns2:stackTrace>
                  <ns2:frame class="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder" file="AnnotationBinder.java" line="1868" method="processElementAnnotations"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder" file="AnnotationBinder.java" line="768" method="processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready"/>
...
```

I have checked and there is no other persistence api jars included.

My external jar list is:

- ant-jakarta-oro-1.6.jar
- antlr-2.7.2.jar
- aspectjrt-1.5.3.jar
- cactus.core.framework.uberjar.javaEE.14-1.8.1.jar
- cactus.integration.maven2-1.8.1.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
- commons-chain-1.2.jar
- commons-codec-1.3.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
- commons-digester-1.8.jar
- commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar
- commons-httpclient-2.0-rc2.jar
- commons-lang3-3.0.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- generic-web-service-schema-4.0.jar
- hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
- hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
- httpunit-1.6.jar
- javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
- jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
- jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
- js-1.5R4.1.jar
- jstl-1.0.2.jar
- jtidy-4aug2000r7-dev.jar
- junit-3.8.2.jar
- nekohtml-1.9.6.jar
- oracle.webservices.standalone.client-11.1.1.jar
- oro-2.0.8.jar
- standard-1.0.6.jar
- struts-core-1.3.10.jar
- struts-el-1.3.10.jar
- struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar
- struts-tiles-1.3.10.jar
- weblogic-webservices-api-1.1.0.0.jar
- xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar
- xml-apis-1.3.03.jar
- xmlParserAPIs-2.2.1.jar

I have checked these and the Hibernate JPA is the only one with the OneToMany class.  I know the problem is a conflict between JPA 1.0 and JPA 2.0 so I just want to know if there is a way around the conflict.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use Hibernate JPA API 2.0?

As mentioned [in WebLogic doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13852/toc.htm#autoId1), WebLogic 10.3.5 seems to roughly support for only one JPA 2.0 provider, which is called [TopLink](http://oss.oracle.com/toplink-essentials-jpa.html).

Maybe you could just remove the `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar` from your classpath and try use TopLink as described in the above mentioned WebLogic documentation.

I'll just give a little note given the docs: by default WebLogic 10.3.5 uses JPA 1.0 in order to maintain Java EE 5 compatibility. Since JPA 2.0 is part of Java EE 6, you have to explicitly enable it.

Comment: The Hibernate JPA jar is a Maven dependency so can't be removed.  I have found the doc you were talking about for JPA 2.0 in Weblogic.  It says that the Weblogic JPA 2.0 have to be applied to Weblogic as a whole and either done as a patch or a manual hack.  Will have to see if anyone else will be using the Weblogic server or I will roll back Hibernate to 3.3 (JPA 1.0). Thanks Paul

Comment: I think 3.4.0 GA was the last version of Hibernate that was JPA 1.

Comment: WebLogic 10.3.5 does support JPA 2.

Comment: @RandyStegbauer Yes it does, but under severe limitations, as I indicated and appears in the doc I linked...

Comment: @yair, I'm sorry.  I should have read more closely.  However, I also wouldn't call adding two JAR files to the classpath severe limitations.

Comment: In the end we removed the OneToMany relationships and adjusted the saving to programmatically iterate through the children to save.  This way we didn't have to lower the version of Hibernate and our deployment to Weblogic could share Weblogic (in dev and test) with another application without breaking it.

Comment: @RandyStegbauer OK. However, the need to use a JPA provider I do not want is severe IMHO :).

Answer (score 4):

WebLogic 10.3.5 *can* support JPA 2, but only after applying a patch as described in this page:  (At least, this is how *I* got it to work for me.)

- https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1112476

It boiled down to editing `setDomainEnv.cmd` and adding `javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_2-0-0.jar` and `com.oracle.jpa2support_1.0.0.0_2-0.jar` to the `PRE_CLASSPATH` environment variable.

For my Windows XP WebLogic installation I added these lines:

```
REM Add JARs for JPA 2.0 at the front of the class path.
set WLS_MODULES=%WL_HOME%\..\modules
set PRE_CLASSPATH=%WLS_MODULES%\javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_2-0-0.jar;%WLS_MODULES%\com.oracle.jpa2support_1.0.0.0_2-0.jar
```

Good Luck,
Randy

Comment: Thanks for that. See above for what we ended up doing

Comment: Does this solution apply also to WebLogic 10.3.6.0? I've exactly the same problem and this solution isn't working..

Comment: Opal, I'm sorry.  I don't know.

Comment: Thanks. It works also for 10.3.6, it was my mistake at the beginning of trying to fix it.